# How can I build a charger for this RC helicopter?

Tags: charger

I have this remote controlled helicopter: http://www.clasohlson.com/se/Radiostyrd-helikopter/31-8071

Currently it is charged by connecting the remote control. However, since the RC runs on batteries, I am thinking it would be nice to charge the helicopter with a battery charger or similar.

I am a complete beginner, and am now looking for how to understand how I can solve this problem. How do I find out what I need? Can I use for example an iPhone charger or anything simliar that many homes has?

Comment: No, you cannot use a phone charger. Although they are called chargers, they're actually power adapters. They have no charge-control circuits whatsoever. To prevent damage to the battery, only charge as the manufacturer says you should.

Comment: It looks very much like a S107G (or a clone), if it has a 3.7V/150mAh Li-Poly battery, you could search [AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-S107G-USB-charger.html) on "S107G USB charger" and you'll find ready built ones for less than a dollar (and in my case free shipping).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a charger which is matched to the battery in your helicopter. Typically these use a single Lithium Polymer cell with a capacity of ~100mAh. To charge this properly the charger must limit current to 0.1A and voltage to 4.2V maximum.

If a Lipo battery is charged incorrectly it may explode and burn up anything around it. This is not just theoretical. I have personally seen the results of some Lipo fires, and they were not pretty.

An iPhone 'charger' is just a 5V power supply that simulates a USB port - the actual charger circuit is built into the phone. Some devices use an external charger, but this will be matched to the battery in the device. Unless you know *exactly* what you are doing, you should only use a charger with the device it was designed for (and similarly, *never* use a charger that was not designed for that device!).

You could use an iPhone 'charger' or other USB power supply to run your own charger, eg. [this one](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1304) from Adafruit. Then you just need to attach the correct plug to suit your heli (perhaps removed from the transmitter).

Comment: Amazing reply. Thanks! According to the site the heli indeed does use a lipo battery (3.7V). I guess it is very risk free then to buy the Adfruit Micro Lipo and start charging.